# Why isn't position: sticky affecting my navbar?

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-position, sticky

There is no overflow property for parent elements. The parent element has a set height. The navigation bar simply won't be sticky no matter what I try. It doesn't work with JavaScript either. I must be missing something. Below is the code. Somebody please tell me what I did wrong:

```css
/* Body */
body{
 margin: 0;
 position: relative;
 height: 100%;
}
/* Header */
.header{
 font-family: sans-serif;
 font-weight: 900;
 background-color: #04042b;
 color: #de215a;
 text-align: center;
 font-size: 200%;
 width: 100%;
}
.header h1{
    margin: 0;
 line-height: 1;
 padding-top: 4%;
 padding-bottom: 4%;
}
/* Navigation Bar */
.navbar{
 background-color: #000005;
 position: sticky;
 top: 0;
 overflow: hidden;
}
.navbar a{
 float: left;
    color: #FFFFE0;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
 font-size: 130%;
 padding: 2%;
}
.navbar a:hover{
 background-color:#E6E6FA ;
    color: black;
}
.navbar a.active{
 background-color: #4682B4;
    color: white;
}
article img{
 height: 100%
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="30">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
 <title>Stuff</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Mainsheet.css">
 <script src="Mainscript.js"type="application/javascript" ></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <header>
   <div class="header">
     <h1>Stuff</h1>
   </div>
 </header>
 <nav>
   <div class="navbar">
     <a class="active" href="">Home</a>
     <a href="">Projects</a>
     <a href="">News</a>  
  <a href="">About</a>
     <a href="">Forum</a>
        <a href="">Contact</a>
     <a href="">Funding&FAQ </a>
   </div>
 </nav>
 <article>
   <h3>Sticky Navigation Example</h3>
        <p>The navbar will stick to the top when you reach its scroll 
        position.</p>
        <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum 
        definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas 
        ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. 
        Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. 
        Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>
        <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum 
        definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas 
        ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. 
        Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. 
        Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>
        <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum 
        definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas 
        ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. 
        Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. 
        Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>
        <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum 
        definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas 
        ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. 
        Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. 
        Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>
        <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum 
        definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera 
        fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis 
        evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint 
        efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>
        <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum 
        definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas 
        ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. 
        Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. 
        Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>
        <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum 
        definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas 
        ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. 
        Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. 
        Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>
 </article>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

Try moving the styles you have for `.navbar` to the parent `nav` root level element (so it sticks to the parent `body`).

```
nav {
    background-color: #000005;
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

```css
/* Body */
body{
 margin: 0;
 position: relative;
 height: 100%;
}
/* Header */
.header{
 font-family: sans-serif;
 font-weight: 900;
 background-color: #04042b;
 color: #de215a;
 text-align: center;
 font-size: 200%;
 width: 100%;
}
.header h1{
    margin: 0;
 line-height: 1;
 padding-top: 4%;
 padding-bottom: 4%;
}
/* Navigation Bar */
nav{
 background-color: #000005;
 position: sticky;
 top: 0;
 overflow: hidden;
}
.navbar a{
 float: left;
    color: #FFFFE0;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
 font-size: 130%;
 padding: 2%;
}
.navbar a:hover{
 background-color:#E6E6FA ;
    color: black;
}
.navbar a.active{
 background-color: #4682B4;
    color: white;
}
article img{
 height: 100%
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="30">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
 <title>Stuff</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Mainsheet.css">
 <script src="Mainscript.js"type="application/javascript" ></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <header>
   <div class="header">
     <h1>Stuff</h1>
   </div>
 </header>
 <nav>
   <div class="navbar">
     <a class="active" href="">Home</a>
     <a href="">Projects</a>
     <a href="">News</a>  
  <a href="">About</a>
     <a href="">Forum</a>
        <a href="">Contact</a>
     <a href="">Funding&FAQ </a>
   </div>
 </nav>
 <article>
   <h3>Sticky Navigation Example</h3>
        <p>The navbar will stick to the top when you reach its scroll 
        position.</p>
        <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum 
        definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas 
        ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. 
        Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. 
        Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>
        <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum 
        definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas 
        ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. 
        Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. 
        Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>
        <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum 
        definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas 
        ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. 
        Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. 
        Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>
        <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum 
        definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas 
        ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. 
        Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. 
        Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>
        <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum 
        definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera 
        fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis 
        evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint 
        efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>
        <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum 
        definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas 
        ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. 
        Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. 
        Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>
        <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum 
        definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas 
        ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. 
        Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. 
        Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>
 </article>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks to you too for the answer. I'm a beginner with web development. You saved me alot of hours of efort(I already spent a few).

Answer (score 3):

Position `sticky` depends on the parent container. Move `nav` inside your `navbar`.

```
<body>
  <header>
    <div class="header">
      <h1>Stuff</h1>
    </div>
  </header>
  <div class="navbar">
    <nav>
      <a class="active" href="">Home</a>
      <a href="">Projects</a>
    </nav>
  </div>
...
```

Comment: Finally. Thanks alot. I was unimaginably stupid for not seeing it. I kept running differint versions for sticky navbars to no avail. You saved me another few hours of useless efort.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand well, when you are scrolling you want header and stays on top.
You should add to `.header` position fixed and `.navbar`  position: fixed;
top: 160px;. Finally to `article` you should add the summary of height from `.header` and `.navbar`. In your case 232px.

```
/* Header */
.header{
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-weight: 900;
    background-color: #04042b;
    color: #de215a;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 200%;
    width: 100%;
  position:fixed;
  top:0;
}

/* Navigation Bar */
.navbar{
    background-color: #000005;
    position: fixed;
    top: 160px;
    overflow: hidden;
   width:100%;
}
article {
  padding-top:232px;
}
```